# CSS3 Columns , force elements to break

Tags: html, css

i really dont know how to ask this question, but i do my best :D

lets start with the pictures :

[image: Picture One]

[image: Picture Two]

[image: Picture three]

im sorry , but i reallyy dont know how to ask this question, i want to break the elements like the first picture, but all i got was the picture 2 and 3
css :

```
.contents{
    background-color: rgb(57, 66, 100);
    border-radius:5px;
    overflow: hidden;
    display:inline-block;
    width:286px;
    margin: 5px 5px 5px 5px;
    float: right;
}
```

html :

```
<div class='contents'>
    <div class='title'>
        <span class='nxnsh'>a</span>
    </div>
    <div class='content'>

        <ul class='nlisty'>
            <li><a href=''>as</a></li>
            <li><a href=''>as</a></li>
            <li><a href=''>as</a></li>
            <li><a href=''>as</a></li>
        </ul>

    </div>

</div>
```

here's the fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/Qaagv/
i want to remove the empty area between top row and bottom row

Comment: If you could please add a fiddle that would help us all answer your question easier. [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/)

Comment: @Geroy290 , please take look http://jsfiddle.net/Qaagv/

Comment: This looks very different from the images shown above, are you sure this is the same?

Comment: yes , but i just copied the important parts of `css` and `html` that have issues with, all i want is remove the empty area between the rows @Geroy290

Comment: You're looking for a [Pinterest style layout](http://cssdeck.com/labs/css-only-pinterest-style-columns-layout), or [this if you're using Bootstrap](http://bragthemes.com/demo/pinstrap/)

Answer (score 1):

A fiddle would make this question easier as it would help us understand your structure.

Can you move over to a structure like this? http://jsfiddle.net/Y6Gfs/

This will create 3 columns layout and in each you can have elements (articles).

```
.column-wrapper {
  width:100%;    
}
.column {
  width:33%;
  float:left;
  display:inline-block;
}
.article {
  background-color:green;
  border: 2px solid pink;    
}

<div class="column-wrapper">
    <div class="column">
        <div class="article"> this is some content for 1</div>        
    </div>
    <div class="column">
        <div class="article"> this ish a not a lot</div>        
        <div class="article"> here is some </div>                
    </div>
    <div class="column">
        <div class="article"> this is a long 3 column layout that will atke up most room </div>                
        <div class="article"> who is anne hatheway anyway </div>        
        <div class="article"> final copy </div>        
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/Qaagv/ here's the fiddle,  i will so glad if i just keep the structure